# To what extent can time be dilated on Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, time, time-dilation, estimation

Though the value would be pretty small, I was still curious about knowing that numeric value.

Comment: On very casual search, particles in the LHC have $\gamma > 7000$: a particle physicist can probably say just how much more.

Comment: @tfb Afaik the electrons (and positrons) in the LEP had bigger gammas (the energy was around $\frac{1}{60}$, but the rest masses were $\frac{1}{2000}$.

Comment: @peterh Yes, I had forgotten that!

Comment: Since we are at it, what's the factor for 0.1eV neutrinos with tens, if not hundreds of GeV energy made at LHC... $10^{12}$?

Comment: @CuriousOne Good answer :-) Although I think in the case of the neutrinos it is unfair to compare to $\gamma=1$, because we can't produce non-relativistic versions of them.

Comment: @peterh: One can always find an observer who is stationary in the frame of the neutrino, so that's not really an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am writing the *gravitational time dilation*, what is caused by the gravity of the Earth.

The spacetime around spherical, not very fast rotating bodies can be described with the [Schwarzschild-metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric):

$c^2 {d \tau}^{2} =
\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right) c^2 dt^2 - \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} dr^2 - r^2 \left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\varphi^2\right)$

On the wiki link can you read more from it. Here we want to know the proper time distance between two points differing only in the $t$-coordinate, so our formula is significantly simplified to:

${d \tau}^2 = \left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r} \right) dt^2$

...where $r_s$ says the distance from the center of the Earth, $r$ is the Earth's gravitational radius (if the Earth would be a non-rotating black hole, it would be its radius, it is 8.9mm). $d\tau$ is the proper time, i.e. the time what the clock measures, while $dt$ is the coordinate time (difference).

Substituting the values, we get:

$d\tau = \sqrt{1-\frac{8.9*10^{-3}}{6.3*10^6}}dt = \sqrt{1-1.4127*10^{-9}}dt = (1-7.063*10^{-10})dt$.

Thus, the time goes here with $1-7.063*10^{-10}$ "speed", compared to the deep space.

It is 1s delay in every 45 years.

---

Note: it is the gravitational time dilation, i.e. how is the time slowed due to gravity. The time delay due to speed (with the well-known $\frac{1}{\sqrt(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})}$ formula is a different effect, and it depends on the speed.)

On the surface of the neutron stars, the time can be even 30-50% slower as far from them.

Answer (score 2):

$$t'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

You can calculate it yourself. Find out what high speed typically is at Earth - (choose the $v$ you wish to compare) - and plug it into the formula. Insert fx $t=100$ and the resulting $t'$ is the real actual time passed. It will be larger for larger speed.

[As an example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation), the ISS astronauts save $0.007$ s during half a year in orbit.

Comment: It is the special relativistic time dilation, it depends on the speed and it is nearly independent from the Earth.